# Alot of the time the error for connecting to a server/realm it says "Invalid session. (Try restarting your game)" How do I fix this from happining?

Tags: minecraft-java-edition-server

[image: Just saying, this is my favorite photograph.]
Please tell me also, the error happens all day.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

Restart the game .if it disent work try logging out and in again . It should work!

Comment: Are you sure? Sometimes it doesn't work for me.

Comment: But okay. I'll try.